# Prevent cmd tab in Fullscreen app

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I want to make some kind of lockscreen (more for myself not for the appstore). Now I would like to disable the cmd tab function or else this won't work because you can just tab out of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `-[NSApplication setPresentationOptions:]`, in particular `NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching`. Depending on the API you're using to go full-screen, you can provide that option at the time you go full-screen. For example, you can add the option to the proposed options in the window delegate method `-window:willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions:`. If you use `-[NSView enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:]` to enter full-screen, you can specify the presentation options in the options dictionary, under the key `NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions`. (Although, if you don't specify that key, then `NSView` will capture the display and prevent Command-Tab by default.)